# Watson speech to text live stream C# code example

Tags: c#, stream, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm trying to build an app in C# that will take an audio stream (from a file for now, but later it will be a web stream) and return transcriptions from Watson in real time as they become available, similar to the demo at https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Does anyone know where I can find some sample code, preferably in C#, that could help me get started?

I tried this, based on the limited documentation at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/src/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.SpeechToText.v1, but I get a BadRequest error when I call RecognizeWithSession. I'm not sure if I'm on the right path here.

```
    static void StreamingRecognize(string filePath)
    {
        SpeechToTextService _speechToText = new SpeechToTextService();
        _speechToText.SetCredential(<user>, <pw>);
        var session = _speechToText.CreateSession("en-US_BroadbandModel");

        //returns initialized
        var recognizeStatus = _speechToText.GetSessionStatus(session.SessionId);

        //  set up observe
        var taskObserveResult = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var result = _speechToText.ObserveResult(session.SessionId);
            return result;
        });

        //  get results
        taskObserveResult.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
        {
            var results = antecedent.Result;
        });

        var metadata = new Metadata();
        metadata.PartContentType = "audio/wav";
        metadata.DataPartsCount = 1;
        metadata.Continuous = true;
        metadata.InactivityTimeout = -1;
        var taskRecognizeWithSession = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                _speechToText.RecognizeWithSession(session.SessionId, "audio/wav", metadata, fs, "chunked");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Watson Developer Cloud - SDK's, in your programming language, you can see one folder called Examples, and you can access the example for using [Speech to Text](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/master/examples/IBM.Watson.SpeechToText.v1.Examples).

The SDK has support for WebSockets which would satisfy your requirement of transcribing more real-time versus uploading an audio file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Transcribe();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-credentials.shtml
        static String username = "<username>";
        static String password = "<password>";

        static String file = @"c:\audio.wav";

        static Uri url = new Uri("wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize");
        
        // these should probably be private classes that use DataContractJsonSerializer 
        // see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        // or the ServiceState class at the end
        static ArraySegment<byte> openingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"action\": \"start\", \"content-type\": \"audio/wav\", \"continuous\" : true, \"interim_results\": true}"
        ));
        static ArraySegment<byte> closingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"action\": \"stop\"}"
        ));
        // ... more in the link below
```

- Access the SDK C# [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk).
- See the API reference for more information [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?curl#introduction).
- One full example using Speech to Text by IBM Watson Developer [here](https://gist.github.com/nfriedly/0240e862901474a9447a600e5795d500).

Comment: Hi, I have a similar requirement. Can you please support if possible ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654946/how-to-send-live-audio-stream-to-ibm-watson-speech-to-text-immediately-without-s